# Limit CPU frequency on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, cpu, battery

I'm looking for a way to limit CPU frequency when system is running on battery.
Solution doesn't have to work exclusively when using battery, it may be in form of bash commands from which I could make script, which I would run on system startup. Draft for the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
sleep 60 #wait one minute
# check whether laptop has ac plugged in
# if not, set frequency limit to what I want
# else, set frequency limit to max
done
```

Comment: I seem to have found answer here, I will make and post answer when I get some free time.
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_frequency_scaling#Setting_maximum_and_minimum_frequencies

Comment: You might want to ask this on Ask Ubuntu. You'd probably get a better answer there.

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/587978/can-i-upper-limit-the-cpu-frequency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of <strike>reinventing the wheel</strike> writing your own script, you may look at `cpufreqd`. Its [config file man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/cpufreqd.conf.5.html) includes example where (lack of) AC power and battery level are taken into consideration.

To install:

```
sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get install cpufreqd
```

Comment: certainly, reinventing the wheel is unnecessary thing to do.  :)
I haven't found `cpufreqd` when googling for solution.

Comment: +1 for humor! :)